# Is this function Lipschitz? $f(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{|y- q_k|}{\sqrt{1 + (y-q_k)^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function

$$f(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\dfrac{|y- q_k|}{\sqrt{1 + (y-q_k)^2}},$$ where $q_k$ is some sequence of rational.

Is this function Lipschitz with respect to $y$?

I am unable to simplify the function to get in the proper form, any hints will be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the outline of what you should do (I want you to do some of the work!):

1. Consider the function $g(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$. Show $g$ is Lipshitz (possibly by appealing to $g'$).
2. Show $|g(x - q_k)|$ is Lipschitz by appealing to the fact that compositions of Lipschitz functions are Lipschitz.
3. Show that $\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2} |g(x - q_k)|$ is an infinite sum of Lipschitz functions, whose Lipschitz constants are summable. Conclude that $\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2} |g(x - q_k)|$ is a Lipschitz function.

Let me know if you get stuck again!

Comment: I have some doubts in last part, how do I show this is summable ?

Comment: @ronin101 Careful: what you wrote is not the definition of Lipschitz. But yes, $\frac{|g(x - q_k)|}{k^2}$ has Lipschitz constant $\frac{L}{k^2}$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $|g(x - q_k)|$ (which is independent of $k$). The series $\sum \frac{L}{k^2}$ is summable (and equals $\frac{\pi^2 L}{6}$).